# Run multiple copies of Speedy or PersistentPerl to be called from Tomcat

Tags: multithreading, perl, tomcat

I have a modern webapp running under Tomcat, which often needs to call some legacy perl code to get some results. Right now, we wrap these in a call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` which is working fine.

However, as the webapp gets busier we are noticing that often the perl is timing out and we need to control this.

I am using `commons-pool` to ensure that only X number of copies can be run at a time, and threads will queue up nicely for a perl instance when they need one, timing out after Y seconds and returning an error (this is fine, the client will just retry).

However we still have the problem that Perl takes a long time to start up, interpret the script, execute and return. At busy times we are doing this 30-50 times per second. It's a beefy machine but it's starting to struggle.

I have read up on `Speedy` and `PersistentPerl` and am considering holding open a copy of this in memory for each object in my pool, so that we do not need to open and close the Perl each time.

Is this a good idea? Any tips for how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Those approaches should reduce the overhead from the start up time of your script. If the script is something that can be run as a CGI program then you might be better offer making it work with [`Plack`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Plack) and running it with a PSGI server. Your Tomcat application could collect and send the request parameters to your script and/or "web application" running in the background.